# problem with PopupPanel - gwt

Tags: java, gwt, panel

I am using PopupPanel and Gwt Canvas for my project. Here when clicked on the canvas-drawing area the popuppanel appears. In my main class i have a private class which extends PopupPanel and this panel is then called in the onModuleLoad(). The code looks something like this:

```
Button b = new Button("Circle");
        b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                DrawingArea d = new DrawingArea(40, 30);
                Circle c = new Circle(20, 15, 20);
                d.add(c);
                dragController.makeDraggable(d);
                dragController.setBehaviorDragStartSensitivity(1);
                boundaryPanel.add(d, 200, 200 );
                //Diagram dia = new Diagram(boundaryPanel);
               /* Shape s = new Shape(d);
                s.showOnDiagram(diagram);*/
                d.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        System.out.println("ERD Circle");
                        Widget w = (Widget)event.getSource();
                        PopUpPanel pop = new PopUpPanel(w);
                        pop.setPopupPosition(w.getAbsoluteLeft() - 150, w.getAbsoluteTop());
                        pop.show();
                    }                   
                });
            }           
        });
```

Here PopUpPanel is the one that extends PopupPanel. Here the code for PopUpPanel:

```
private static class PopUpPanel extends PopupPanel{

    Button connect = new Button("Connect");
    Button delete = new Button("Delete");
    Button detail = new Button("Detail");

    public PopUpPanel(final Widget widget){
       super(true);
       VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
       vp.add(connect);
       vp.add(delete);
       vp.add(detail);

       setWidget(vp);
    }
}
```

Now the problem i am facing is:

When i click on the canvas-drawing area PopupPanel appears together with an error. Here are the error details:

```
[ERROR] Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error): Invalid class string


 number: -2147221005
 description: Invalid class string


    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.PopupImplIE6.onShow(Native Method)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel$ResizeAnimation.onInstantaneousRun(PopupPanel.java:257)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel$ResizeAnimation.setState(PopupPanel.java:180)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel.setState(PopupPanel.java:1189)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel.show(PopupPanel.java:794)
    at com.e.r.d.client.ERD1$4$1.onClick(ERD1.java:177)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager$HandlerRegistry.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:65)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager$HandlerRegistry.access$1(HandlerManager.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:178)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:52)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:90)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1320)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventAndCatch(DOM.java:1299)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1262)
```

Any input would be of great help.

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't `System.out.println("ERD Circle");` at fault? Use `GWT.log` or gwt-log instead.

Comment: I am just using that to see if the click event is working or not. previously i did not have any problem with this line of code. I have also tried running this by removing the above statement with no success.

Comment: Eh, it was a long shot anyway - atm, I can't test the code :/

Comment: It seems someone had a similar issue (http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/b095e5cfed822b43/4d19dacd98351373?lnk=gst&q=%22Invalid+class+string%22#4d19dacd98351373) - I was wondering if http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#CwSuggestBox works OK for you on your IE6 (it works fine here on IE6) - if it shows the same error, then it's a problem with your installation IE6, not GWT (a problem with IE6? No way! ;)).

Comment: I am having problem with the showcase example. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: For the time being you can switch to OOPHM (if you are not using it yet): http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/UsingOOPHM and wait for the GWT team to sort it out (you might wanna check GWT's issue tracker to see if they have an issue opened for this, and if not, open one). If you wanna stick with IE.. someone suggested that IE's plugins might be the cause of this behavior - do you have any installed? Try disabling/uninstalling all, and then progressively re-enable/reinstall one after another, till you find the troublemaker (and report back here so that others can benefit :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. This happens due to missing Microsoft JScript registration. once i registered "regsvr32 jscript.dll" it is working fine. thanks.